# Proof of Chernoff Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

The Chernoff inequality, as stated in Theorem 2.1.3 of [this book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf), says that for $X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}$ independent scalar random variables with $|{X_{i}}|\le K$, mean $\mu_{i}$, and variance $\sigma_{i}^{2}$, and for all $\lambda > 0$, we have the bound $\mathbb{P}(|{S_{n}-\mu|}\ge \lambda \sigma)\le C \text{max}(\text{exp}(-c\lambda^2)),\text{exp}(-c\lambda\sigma/K))$, where $S_{n}$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$, $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu_{i}$, $\sigma^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_{i}^{2}$, and $C,c > 0$ are absolute constants.  For the purposes of this question, it suffices to consider $K=1$,$\mu_{i}=0$.

The proof proceeds by applying the Hoeffding lemma to obtain a bound on the moment generating functions: $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_{i}})\le e^{O(t^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2})}$.  This leads to the inequality $\mathbb{P}(S_{n}\ge \lambda\sigma)\le \text{exp}((O(t^{2}\sigma^{2})-t\lambda\sigma))$.  At this point, the author chooses to optimize this with respect to $t\in [0,1]$.  However, the Hoeffding lemma applies for all $t > 0$.

I do not understand why the restriction to $t\in [0,1]$ is made here.  Without this restriction, the bound obtained after optimization will not contain a maximum.  Can someone explain either (1) why the restriction is necessary or (2) why the maximum in the theorem statement is necessary?

For completeness, the Hoeffding lemma states that $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_{i}})\le 1 + O(t^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2}e^{O(t(b-a))})$, for all $t > 0$.

edit: It appears that $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_{i}})\le e^{O(t^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2})}$ cannot be true in general unless $t$ is bounded.  This is probably the issue in my reasoning.  I'll leave the question up in case someone wanted to answer.

Comment: Why can't that be true? Isn't that the second inequality in Hoeffding's lemma?

Comment: @broncoAbierto For example, if $X$ is $0$ with probability $1-2p$, $1$ with probability $p$, and $-1$ with probability $p$, then its variance is $2p$.  The proposed bound on the moment generating function has the form $e^{C2pt^2}$.  When $p=0$ the MGF and the proposed bound are both $1$.  However, the MGF is $1-2p+pe^{t} + pe^{-t}$.  Comparing the derivatives at $0$ wrt $p$, the MGF is larger for some small $p$ when $\lambda$ is large.  Maybe there is an easier explanation?

Comment: Can't you just choose the constant so that it holds?

Comment: @broncoAbierto The constant should not depend on $\sigma_i^2$, which is $2p$ in the example I gave.  Once you pick the constant, there is always a choice of sufficiently small $p$ and sufficiently large $t$ that shows the inequality is false.

Answer (score 2):

You want to minimize, not maximize. You know the inequality holds for any $t$, so you just want to make it as tight as you can.

The restriction is not necessary. It's sufficient. If you inspect the inequality and consider different cases (that is, how big or small $\lambda$ is w.r.t. $\sigma$), you'll see that you can consider a $t\in[0,1]$ and pick constants $C,c$ so that the result holds.

Comment: If the restriction isn't necessary, then I should always choose $t$ to be the global minimum of the right hand side of the inequality.  This always gives a bound like $\text{exp}(-c\lambda^{2})$?  Why would I choose $t=1$ instead of the global minimum?

Comment: I guess it's because it just works. Essentially, if $\lambda$ is large then $t=1$ works. Otherwise you need to tinker a bit more to get the bound. So it doesn't really make a big difference, but in my opinion it makes the proof more easily readable. I'm not entirely sure if this is actually why Tao put that there, but to me it sounds like a possible reason.

Comment: Note that the goal here is to prove the inequality, not really minimize the r.h.s. So anything that shows the result is valid.

Comment: I get your point, that there is nothing wrong with the choice $t=1$, but I don't see why the bound would be reported as a maximum of two quantities when it is known that one of them is always smaller than the other.

Comment: But it isn't! It depends on whether $\lambda$ or $\sigma$ is larger, and that's precisely what makes $t$ get smaller than 1 in some cases.

Comment: Also, maybe there's a stronger reason to bound $t$ (as you pointed out above, haven't done the math) but at the end of the day, it doesn't really matter. The result follows.